# How to extract S3uri as string in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

am trying to execute the below code in sagemaker pipeline

```
train_data = TrainingInput(
    s3_data = step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["train_data"].S3Output.S3Uri+'/training.txt',
    distribution="FullyReplicated",
    content_type="text/plain",
    s3_data_type="S3Prefix",
)
```

I keep getting this error `AttributeError: 'Properties' object has no attribute 'path'` but am not sure how to extract the URI as string

I can put that in a general question, how to access/print `properties` data like `step_train.properties.ModelArtifacts.S3ModelArtifacts` will print  `<sagemaker.workflow.properties.Properties at 0x7fa7d68acbd0>` instead of the models path

Answer (score 0):

You're suppose to have a preceding Processing step with the mentioned output like so:

```
step_process = ProcessingStep(
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/train_data"), ] ... )
```

Try to follow this [example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/abalone_build_train_deploy/sagemaker-pipelines-preprocess-train-evaluate-batch-transform_outputs.ipynb), then change it to your use case.

Also note that you have some kind of dot following `["train_data"].` (2nd line), instead of a comma (maybe it's a paste issue).

Comment: within the link you provided,  this is what matches my case, and I need simply to add a string to the URI
train_args = xgb_train.fit(
    inputs={
        "train": TrainingInput(
            s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs["train"].S3Output.S3Uri,
            content_type="text/csv",
        ),
        "validation": TrainingInput(
            s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                "validation"
            ].S3Output.S3Uri,
            content_type="text/csv",
        ),
    }
)